# pandas bdate_range freq=monthly not returning only business days

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

Using 'B' as freq will return me only the business days

```
list(pd.bdate_range("2020-08-26", "2021,8,11", freq="B"))
```

Using 'M' as freq will use monthly sampling BUT it will also include weekend-days. How can I remove those weekend days from the output?

```
list(pd.bdate_range("2020-08-26", "2021,8,11", freq="M"))
```

Comment: try this:`pd.pd.bdate_range("2020-08-26", "2021-8-11", freq="BM")`

Comment: you're my man, thanks!